# How can a Judo fight be won?

Tags: rules, judo

I recently watched a Judo fight and I was confused about the scoring system. How exactly can a fight be won?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are (as of 2018) four ways how a fight can be won:

1. **Ippon** - An Ippon ("full point") is awarded, when either the opponent is thrown on the back with force, control and speed or when the opponent is fixed in Osae-komi for 20 seconds or when the opponent surrenders after an arm lock or a strangulation. Every Ippon ends the fight immediately.
2. **Waza-ari** - If you perform a technique, that does not fully match the criterias for Ippon, you will be awarded an Waza-ari ("half point"). Two Waza-aris result in an Ippon ("Waza-ari-awasete-Ippon") and end the fight immediately. Also the fighter with more Waza-aris wins, when the fight time (usually 4 mins) is over.
3. **Fight end** - In case of a draw, the fight will continue in *Golden Score*-mode. The fighter that scores the first score will immediately end the fight and be declared winner.

   Some smaller tournaments don't have Golden score but use a *Hantei* instead. In this case the referee decides who fought better and declares this Judoka the winner.
4. **Hansoku-make** - For major or repetitive rule breaks, actions against the spirit of Judo or the performance of techniques that put the fighters health in danger a *Hansoku-Make* can be given. This penalty is a disqualification and ends the fight immediately. The punished fighter may or may not (depending of the circumstances) continue to fight in the tournament.

More information can be seen in a video published by the IJF (international Judo federation) to inform about the 2018 rules:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgfKasoI5yc

Answer (score 1):

| Win | Ways to achieve this |
| --- | --- |
| Ippon | - throw opponent flat on their back with skill, speed, and force - submit opponent with armlock or strangle - pin opponent for 20s |
| Waza-ari (half point) + time runs out | - throw opponent but they only land on one side of their back - pin opponent for 10s |
| Waza-ari-awasete-ippon (two half points) | Score two waza-ari |

One can also win (as in other sports) if the opponent is disqualified or must withdraw from the match:

| Win | Ways to achieve this |
| --- | --- |
| Hansoku-gachi | - opponent gets 3 shido (minor penalties) - opponent gets hansoku-make (major penalty) |
| Fusen-gachi | Opponent does not appear to match |
| Kiken-gachi | Opponent withdraws |
| Fuso-gachi | Opponent withdraws due to injury |